# Onsen UI menu.toggle() is not working after adding navigator with sliding menu

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I want to add a page before my sliding menu page. I succeeded to accomplish that. But, now I can't access menu.toggle();
I logged the menu object, that says undefined. And I've also tried navi.menu but that also doesn't seem to work. This is the closest solution I've got but no menu.toggle
[Onsen UI - Using Slide-Menu just for specifics pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487885/onsen-ui-using-slide-menu-just-for-specifics-pages) here is my code

```
<ons-navigator title="Navigation" var="navi" page="homePage.html">

    </ons-navigator>

    <ons-template id="homePage.html">
        <ons-page ng-controller="mainPageController">
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">PHPTRAVELS</div>
                <div class="right">
                    <ons-toolbar-button>Exit</ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            <ons-row class="home-page">
                <ons-col>
                    <ons-list>
                        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" 
                            style="line-height: 25px; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px;" 
                            ng-show="modules[2].status"
                            ng-click="navi.pushPage('home.html')">
                            <ons-row>
                                <ons-col width="70px" class="ic">
                                    <ons-icon icon="fa fa-building" size="50px"></ons-icon>
                                </ons-col>
                                <ons-col>
                                    <div class="title">Hotels</div>
                                    <div class="description">Find the perfect hotel room</div>
                                </ons-col>
                            </ons-row>
                        </ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" style="line-height: 25px; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px;" 
                            ng-show="modules[6].status || modules[7].status">
                            <ons-row>
                                <ons-col width="70px" class="ic">
                                    <ons-icon icon="fa fa-plane" size="50px"></ons-icon>
                                </ons-col>
                                <ons-col>
                                    <div class="title">Flights</div>
                                    <div class="description">Get the best flight</div>
                                </ons-col>
                            </ons-row>
                        </ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" style="line-height: 25px; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px;" 
                            ng-show="modules[3].status">
                            <ons-row>
                                <ons-col width="70px" class="ic">
                                    <ons-icon icon="fa fa-briefcase" size="50px"></ons-icon>
                                </ons-col>
                                <ons-col>
                                    <div class="title">Tours</div>
                                    <div class="description">Your vacation awaits</div>
                                </ons-col>
                            </ons-row>
                        </ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" style="line-height: 25px; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px;" 
                            ng-show="modules[1].status">
                            <ons-row>
                                <ons-col width="70px" class="ic">
                                    <ons-icon icon="fa fa-car" size="50px"></ons-icon>
                                </ons-col>
                                <ons-col>
                                    <div class="title">Cars</div>
                                    <div class="description">Seek a deal on wheels</div>
                                </ons-col>
                            </ons-row>
                        </ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" style="line-height: 25px; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px;" 
                            ng-show="modules[0].status">
                            <ons-row>
                                <ons-col width="70px" class="ic">
                                    <ons-icon icon="fa fa-leanpub" size="50px"></ons-icon>
                                </ons-col>
                                <ons-col>
                                    <div class="title">Blog</div>
                                    <div class="description">Travel news portal</div>
                                </ons-col>
                            </ons-row>
                        </ons-list-item>
                    </ons-list>
                </ons-col>
            </ons-row>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-sliding-menu
        menu-page="menu.html" main-page="home.html" side="left"
        var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px">
    </ons-sliding-menu>

    <ons-template id="menu.html">
      <ons-page modifier="menu-page">

        <br><br>
        <ons-list class="menu-list">
            <ons-list-item menuitem class="menu-item selected" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('home.html', {closeMenu: true});">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Home
            </ons-list-item>

            <ons-list-item menuitem class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('browsehotels.html', {closeMenu: true});">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Browse Hotels
            </ons-list-item>

            <ons-list-item menuitem class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('specialoffers.html', {closeMenu: true});">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Special Offers
            </ons-list-item>        

            <ons-list-item menuitem class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('blog.html', {closeMenu: true});">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Blog
            </ons-list-item>        

            <ons-list-item menuitem class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('mybookings.html', {closeMenu: true});">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;My Bookings
            </ons-list-item>        

            <ons-list-item menuitem class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('contactus.html', {closeMenu: true});">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Us
            </ons-list-item>        

        </ons-list>

      </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="home.html">
    <!-- <ons-navigator var="nav"> -->
      <ons-page ng-controller="homeController">
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="left">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle();">
              <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
            </ons-toolbar-button>
          </div>
          <div class="center text-center">PHPTRAVELS</div>
          <div class="right">
            <ons-toolbar-button>
                <!-- <ons-icon icon="refresh" size="30px" spin="{{isFetching}}" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon> -->
                <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" ng-show="isFetching" spin="{{isFetching}}"></ons-icon>
            </ons-toolbar-button>
          </div>
        </ons-toolbar>
<div>some text</div>
</ons-page>


</ons-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `toggle()`, `open()` and `close()` for the sliding menu are deprecated.

You can use the `toggleMenu([options])` method instead: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-sliding-menu.html#method-toggleMenu

It seems like you want a page before the sliding menu so I made a small example:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/XJOQwy

Comment: I tried your code but had to remove the navigator. The navigator and the sliding menu were on the same level. You need to put one inside the other. This is the fixed code: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/XJOQwy

Comment: http://codepen.io/vnguyen972/pen/ghKcB
By running this codepen example it says
Error: You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator".
    at Class.module.factory.Class.extend._createPageElementAndLinkFunction (onsenui.js:9186)
    at Class.<anonymous> (onsenui.js:9316)
    at processQueue (angular.js:12914)
    at angular.js:12930
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14123)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:13939)
    at angular.js:14161
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4877)
    at angular.js:5250

Comment: I have another page before going to this sliding menu page. For that purpose I need to use navigator. None of the solutions around the internet  are working.

Comment: Just put the sliding menu in a template and push that page in the navigator.

Comment: Same error
Error: You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator".

Comment: Oh, I maybe forgot to press save.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73846/discussion-between-andreas-argelius-and-danish-jamil).

Comment: Great... Thanks a lot :) I needed to put sliding menu in ons page inside template